# Remove a shared email mailbox from outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My boss likes to have the inboxes of former employees shared with him in case they receive any emails that are important to current projects.

Recently he just asked me to remove a few of these mailboxes.  I was able to do that by logging into admin.microsoft, going to Users->Active users, finding the email to remove, going to Read and manage permissions under Mailbox permissions and removing my boss.

However, this last former employee - when I click on him and go to the Mail tab I see `This user doesn't have an Exchange Online license.`

I tried to locally do this on my bosses outlook.  I went to File->Account Settings->Account Settings but under the email tab I only see my bosses email, not this employees.

Trying to right click the employee name and selecting  `Close 'Former employee'...` gives me an error `The group of folders is associated with an email account.  To remove the account, click the File Tab, and on the info tab, click Account Settings.  Select the email account, then click Remove.`  However, as mentioned, I don't see that email account when I follow these steps - only my bosses account.

Any ideas what is going wrong here and how I can remove this person's inbox from my bosses outlook?

Comment: Is your boss using the Outlook desktop app, or Outlook web app? Also, if an employee does not have an 'Exchange Online License', it could just be a shared mailbox where it may be easier to edit from the Exchange Admin Center.

Answer (score 0):

It's suggested that you could try the below method:

[image]

References: [Can’t remove additional Exchange mailboxes](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/673)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.